# Preventing the optimizer from optimizing a variable away in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

Sometimes when writing benchmarks I have found it useful to use an "opaque" function which prevents the optimizer from completely removing a variable.  On gcc and clang I have an implementation using inline assembly which seems to work as I want in all cases I have tested so far.  Here is a simple example of what I am interested in ([example on godbolt](http://goo.gl/03EGrJ)):

```
template<class T> 
void opaque(T&& t)
{
    asm volatile("" : "+r" (t));
}

int test(int a) { return a + 5; }

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    opaque(a);
    return test(a);
}
```

The above code generates the following assembly:

```
movl    $10, %eax
addl    $5, %eax
ret
```

whereas, without the opaque function it generates:

```
movl    $15, %eax
ret
```

How would I write an equivalent to the opaque function for the visual studio compiler (specifically 2013)?

Comment: Use a global volatile variable?

Comment: Try `__declspec(noinline)` to prevent compiler inlining your opaque function and therefore seeing nothing happens to `a` in it. I'm not sure using `a` after passing to opaque as `&&` is correct, but I'm not sure it is incorrect either. Non-const reference should suffice.

Comment: @Neil Kirk, with all optimizations enabled the __declspec(noinline) does not seem to have any effect.  The assembly msvc generates is just returning 15.  Also, would you mind elaborating on why using `a` after is has been passed to a function taking a universal reference would be problematic?

Comment: Have you tried declaring the variable as `volatile`?

Comment: Try putting the body of the function in another source file and disable whole program optimization?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's very late for answering this but I'm having a similar problem. My constellation is VSCode + CMake + MSVC, and I've done some researching and found the following Visual Studio article: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/compiler-optimizes-out-some-variables-in-release-b/276808

> If you are concerned that the compiler is optimizing in the root of a benchmark, there are two general approaches which I find effective: 1.
> Strategic use of volatile variables to prevent the above optimizations from kicking in. 2. Disable optimizations around the "main" function with #pragma optimize("", off) / #pragma optimize("", on). I prefer option 2, where I find the intent more clear.

I tested the option with #pragma optimize("", on / off) around the main function and it actually works.

The other option is of course disable optimization entirely with /Od tag for compiler. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/od-disable-debug?view=msvc-170)