# Hide the boost function inside a DLL

Tags: c++, boost, dll

I am working on a DLL project and I am using the BOOST library, I am also using a module-definition file to avoid the name-mangling of the compiler so that its easy to call my function from this DLL. But my problem is that a whole lot of BOOST functions area also getting exported. I am using a DLL viewer to look at the function my DLL exposes, and to my surprise, there are a lot of BOOST there. (The function I want to export are there as well, so no issues there) any idea why this is happening? 
(I dont have enough reputation to post images, any suggestions how I can do that? pastebin or something?)

```
`GetNameOfUsbIf     Exported Function   
GetNumberOfUsbIfs   Exported Function   
Initialize          Exported Function   
int __stdcall SET_SYSTEM_NOTIFY_CALLBACK(void (__cdecl*)(enum SYSTEM_EVENT_MSP))        Exported Function   
private: static class boost::archive::detail::extra_detail::map<class boost::archive::binary_iarchive> & __cdecl boost::serialization::singleton<class boost::archive::detail::extra_detail::map<class boost::archive::binary_iarchive> >::get_instance(void)       Exported Function   
private: static class boost::archive::detail::extra_detail::map<class boost::archive::binary_iarchive> & boost::serialization::singleton<class boost::archive::detail::extra_detail::map<class boost::archive::binary_iarchive> >::instance     Exported Function`
```

I am using the `__declspec(dllexport)` prefix to my function that I wish to export which is controlled by a compiler flag. 
This above is a copy-paste of the text from the dllViewer
Any suggestions what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but the problem is current it seems, because I run into it. So I'm offering my findings.

A DLL of mine which uses a static lib which in turn uses [Boost.Serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) exports these symbols in addition to the desired ones:

```
public: static void __cdecl boost::serialization::singleton_module::unlock(void)
private: static bool & __ptr64 __cdecl boost::serialization::singleton_module::get_lock(void)
public: static bool __cdecl boost::serialization::singleton_module::is_locked(void)
bool `private: static bool & __ptr64 __cdecl boost::serialization::singleton_module::get_lock(void)'::`2'::lock
public: static void __cdecl boost::serialization::singleton_module::lock(void)
```

I don't have `boost::serialization::singleton` there, but that may be due to the fact that I'm not actually using Boost.Serialization, just including some of its headers for historic reasons.

After some inspection in the Boost source code (1.67.0 in my case) I found this in `boost/serialization/singleton.hpp`:

```
BOOST_DLLEXPORT static void lock(){
```

And you may have already guess it, that macro is defined as `__declspec(dllexport)`.

So because I'm (transitively) including this header in my sources these symbols get exported automatically. (see [Exporting from a DLL Using __declspec(dllexport)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-declspec-dllexport?view=msvc-170) for more on this)

**So how can this be fixed?**

Personally I'm in the lucky situation that I could remove all the Boost.Serialization headers in my project since they were not used. After a rebuild the symbols were gone.

If one is not so lucky, life is becoming hard. It seems that there is no opt-out macro. (well, usually one would not want to NOT export symbols marked as `BOOST_DLLEXPORT`). But the code contains this information in the comments:

```
// note usage of BOOST_DLLEXPORT.  These functions are in danger of
// being eliminated by the optimizer when building an application in
// release mode. Usage of the macro is meant to signal the compiler/linker
// to avoid dropping these functions which seem to be unreferenced.
// This usage is not related to autolinking.
```

So if you really need to remove these symbols you can try to modify the Boost headers and remove the `BOOST_DLLEXPORT` from the affected symbols in this one header, this will definitely remove those symbols. Then test if everything works, if so party hard.
Otherwise since you are on MSVC you could try some tricks to stop the optimizer, e.g., as decribed here: [Preventing the optimizer from optimizing a variable away in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24664865/1969455). If this also does not help you are pretty much out of luck.

This does not feel right, but it is the only solution I can think of. (apart from filing a bug with Boost which may not help anyway)